# Reindexing after a pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Consider the following dataset:

[image: dataset]

After running the code:

```
convert_dummy1 = convert_dummy.pivot(index='Product_Code', columns='Month', values='Sales').reset_index()
```

The data is in the right form, but my index column is named 'Month', and I cannot seem to remove this at all. I have tried codes such as the below, but it does not do anything.

```
del convert_dummy1.index.name
```

I can save the dataset to a csv, delete the ID column, and then read the csv - but there must be a more efficient way.

Dataset after reset_index():

[image]

Comment: add `.rename_axis(None, 1)` after the pivot and before the `.reset_index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
convert_dummy1

Month   Product_Code      0   1   2   3   4
    0        10133.9      0   0   0   0   0
    1        10146.9    120  80  60   0 100

convert_dummy1.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(convert_dummy1.index))
del convert_dummy1.columns.name
convert_dummy1

    Product_Code      0   1   2   3   4
0        10133.9      0   0   0   0   0
1        10146.9    120  80  60   0 100
```

Comment: Adding drop=True removes the Product_Code column.

Comment: Sorry can you post the dataframe after `reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

Since you pivot with `columns="Month"`, each column in output corresponds to a month. If you decide to reset index after the pivot, you should check column names with `convert_dummy1.columns.value` which should return in your case :

```
array(['Product_Code', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=object)
```

while `convert_dummy1.columns.names` should return:

```
FrozenList(['Month'])
```

So to rename `Month`, use `rename_axis` function:

```
convert_dummy1.rename_axis('index',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
index   Product_Code    1   2   3   4   5
0       10133           NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0
1       10234           NaN 0.0 NaN NaN NaN
2       10245           0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3       10345           NaN NaN NaN 0.0 NaN
4       10987           NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN
```

---

If you wish to reproduce it, this is my code:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Product_Code':[10133,10245,10234,10987,10345], 'Month': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Sales': [0,0,0,1,0]})
df2=df1.pivot_table(index='Product_Code', columns='Month', values='Sales').reset_index().rename_axis('index',axis=1)
```